# Error with photo fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am crafting a view to produce a directory of contacts, with contact_image as one of the fields (rewritten to wrap [IMAGE_URL] in an img element).
My output is headed by an error for each call to the image fetcher:

```
Notice: Undefined index: photo in CRM_Contact_Page_ImageFile->run() (line 44 of /srv/www/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/ImageFile.php).
```

I'm not certain if this refers to a database or array index. 
Using CiviCRM version 4.6.10 on Drupal 7.44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working, the last action before it did so was me updating the views module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 4.6.10; but on a CiviCRM 4.7.8 - this is working as below - out of the box - no rewriting and no views-views-fields.tpl.php required.

**In CiviCRM:**

[image]

**In Views:**

[image]